# node-rdkafka producer not connecting/producing in docker alpine but running perfectly locally

Tags: node.js, docker, apache-kafka

I have the following setup

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk --no-cache --update add python3 py3-pip alpine-sdk bash librdkafka openssl-dev

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5004
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

**A bills.js file**

```
import fs from "fs";
import readline from "readline";

function readAllLines(path) {    
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Test file access directly, so that we can fail fast.
    // Otherwise, an ENOENT is thrown in the global scope by the readline internals.
    try {
      fs.accessSync(path, fs.constants.R_OK);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    
    let lines = [];
    
    const reader = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(path),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    
    reader
      .on('line', (line) => lines.push(line))
      .on('close', () => resolve(lines));
  });
}

const configFromPath = async function configFromPath(path) {
  const lines = await readAllLines(path);
  return lines
    .filter((line) => !/^\s*?#/.test(line))
    .map((line) => line
      .split('=')
      .map((s) => s.trim()))
    .reduce((config, [k, v]) => {
      config[k] = v;
      return config;
    }, {});
};
// Copy
// Next, we are going to create the producer application by pasting the following code into a file named producer.js:

import Kafka from "node-rdkafka";

function createConfigMap(config) {
  if (config.hasOwnProperty('security.protocol')) {
    return {
      'bootstrap.servers': config['bootstrap.servers'],
      'sasl.username': config['sasl.username'],
      'sasl.password': config['sasl.password'],
      'security.protocol': config['security.protocol'],
      'sasl.mechanisms': config['sasl.mechanisms'],
      'dr_msg_cb': true,
      'request.required.acks': 1
    }
  } else {
    return {
      'bootstrap.servers': config['bootstrap.servers'],
      'dr_msg_cb': true
    }
  }
}

function createProducer(config, onDeliveryReport) {

  const producer = new Kafka.Producer(createConfigMap(config));

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    producer
      .on('ready', () => resolve(producer))
      .on('delivery-report', onDeliveryReport)
      .on('event.error', (err) => {
        console.warn('event.error', err);
        reject(err);
      });
    producer.connect();
  });
}


async function produceExample(value,key) {
  
  let configPath ="kafka.properties";
  const config = await configFromPath(configPath);
value = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(value));
  let topic = "bill";
  const producer = await createProducer(config, (err, report) => {
    if (err) {
      console.warn('Error producing', err)
    } else {
      const {topic, key, value} = report;
      let k = key.toString().padEnd(10, ' ');
      console.log(`Produced event to topic ${topic}: key = ${k} value = ${value}`);
    }
  });
  producer.produce(topic, -1, value, key);

  producer.flush(10000, () => {
    producer.disconnect();
  });
}
```

Here's my config file

```
bootstrap.servers=xxxx.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 
security.protocol=SASL_SSL 
sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN 
sasl.username=xxxxxx 
sasl.password=xxxxxx 
# Best practice for higher availability in librdkafka clients prior to 1.7 
session.timeout.ms=45000
```

If I debug this code and write a console.log just below producer.connect() it's working but not comming down to

```
producer.produce(topic, -1, value, key);
```

I have tested this code without dockerizing and it's working fine.

I also see some errors while building node-rdkafka when Dockerfile run npm install

I think the node-rdfkafka is not building properly and that's causing the issue of stuck behavior.

Here are some images of the build error I suspect
[Many of these types of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpdhZ.png)

Edit:
I'm now getting this error now even after making librdkafka from the source. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omm4T.png)

Comment: Please show your config object / file. You could also add a log into `producer.on('ready'` to tell you that it should be connected and ready to send data

Comment: Here's my config file
`
bootstrap.servers=xxxx.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.username=xxxxxx
sasl.password=xxxxxx

# Best practice for higher availability in librdkafka clients prior to 1.7
session.timeout.ms=45000`

I can see it properly if I console log it, Also 
`producer.on('ready', () =>{ console.log("ready"); resolve(producer);})
`
 
I don't see any console log in this case

Comment: You say you see build errors? Can you share them?

Comment: Here are some screenshots with pointers on code I don't get what those mean.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FRdRPvfgpRzuPmjDgbx-YRrhCDkhn2eY?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm getting a new error though

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uaSRIkelosbhC8I8gxuIV7AtwPM8FKsn/view?usp=sharing

I have tried making librdkafka from source but still getting same error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details or errors rather than Google drive

Comment: @OneCricketeer have a look now

Comment: I'm not sure about alpine, but in the second image, `libnode` needs installed, and Ubuntu/Debian have a `libnode-dev` package you can download. Alternatively, you can try KafkaJS instead of node-rdkafka

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  I am seeing a similar issue with docker.